# Format graph with pandas/matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following situation:

1. There is a time series displayed as ohlc bars.
2. There is a statistic over the same series displayed as line.
3. There is a markup displayed as vertical lines. Some of them located after last entry of my time series.

If I draw just my ohlc bars then I see in the display all bars and all markup lines. The code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()
entries = [(x["Date"], x["Open"], x["High"], x["Low"], x["Close"]) for (i, x) in dataFrame.iterrows()]
candlestick_ohlc(ax, entries)
for date in markupDates:
    ax.plot([date, date], [low, high], "r--")
```

[Without line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSm9R.png)

But when I draw line of my statistic then I get displayed only time series. To see markup lines at the right side I need to roll manually. The code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()
entries = [(x["Date"], x["Open"], x["High"], x["Low"], x["Close"]) for (i, x) in dataframe.iterrows()]
candlestick_ohlc(ax, entries)
dataFrame.plot(ax = ax, x="Date", y=["Line"])
for date in markupDates:
    ax.plot([date, date], [low, high], "r--")
```

[With line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7De3Q.png)

I don't want markup lines at the right side to be truncated when I draw my statistic line. How can I achive this?

Comment: Can you include a picture of what get in your question, and point out how that is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the initial message.

Comment: Easy, change your `xlim` using `ax.set_xlim([min, max])` to match the full extents of your data. Whatever those might be... Do it after plotting everything you want to plot.

Comment: Thank you, now it works as I want.
But is it really I need to manually handle this case? Maybe there is native way to achieve it and get out of head this case?